# obtain data from localstorage in Python

Tags: python

I'm still bit new to Python and trying to understand. If you could help me out it would be appreciated!

My issue is that I want to grab my authorization token from twitter.com that is stored in my local storage. Is there a way in Python to obtain the auth_token from localstorage and save it to a text file?

(I know how to write things to a text file but I'm having issues grabbing the auth token. I'm using playwright async and already tried it through the cookies and pasting them in a JSON file, but this results in that the "auth_token" is sometimes placed in the JSON file as:

```
['cookies'][9]['value']
```

or:
 `['cookies'][7]['value']` `['cookies'][8]['value']`

Is there a way that I can find this in an easier way? The format looks like:

```
{
    "cookies": [{
        "name": "auth_token",
        "value": "22b23d52e7c639f123456ed451dfe9ebd9d439d3",
        "domain": ".twitter.com",
        "path": "/",
        "expires": 1816242826,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "secure": true,
        "sameSite": "None"
    }, {
        "name": "ct0",
        "value": "1547663d5b6a5b5c857b726964d9e10c7eb4654c1b210c345d008d28d526f43e7c5a8f4dcfaaead4281bac844cfee5a642fa5a7e7e9824405817de778bbd970f712f5de0cf01bf352de94989da6eb349",
        "domain": ".twitter.com",
        "path": "/",
        "expires": 1816242827,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "secure": true,
        "sameSite": "Lax"
    }, {
        "name": "twid",
        "value": "u%3D1550750937400360960",
        "domain": ".twitter.com",
        "path": "/",
        "expires": 1690098828,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "secure": true,
        "sameSite": "None"
    }, {
        "name": "_s",
        "value": "CgdiXZmky9MlkvLhFqnr4TxEU0eoZnJT4Eir8QAH%2FZ4SZENccyKmnFwtUXTz9BKd",
        "domain": ".app.link",
        "path": "/",
        "expires": 1690098784,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "secure": true,
        "sameSite": "None"
    }]  
}
```

Issue is that the "auth_token" is stored in [7/8/9] which is different every time. Is there a way to do it like

```
['cookies']['auth_token']['value']
```

right now I have:

```
with open('t.json') as auth_obtainer:
    authfile =json.load(auth_obtainer)
    auth_token = json.dumps(authfile['cookies'][9]['value']).replace('"',"")
    print(auth_token)
```

but sometimes it's located differently in the JSON file so it gives me the wrong value

Comment: Python runs on the server, local storage is in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop to iterate over dictionary contained in cookies and check if it contains name which has value equal to "auth_token" or not, if it does then access the "value" key of that dictionary.

```
with open('t.json') as f:
    content = json.load(f)
    cookies = content['cookies']
    
    for data in cookies:
        if data['name'] == 'auth_token':
            auth_token = data['value']
    
    print(auth_token)
```